# How to quantify the (unit-)testability of a piece of code?

Tags: unit-testing, code-quality, measurement

I'd like to measure, how well unit-testable is my code. I don't have a concrete idea, how it should look like, but my logic is:

There are a lot of formally checkable and quantifiable criteria for well testable code:

- usage of global/static functions/variables,
- [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity),
- DI vs. wild direct instantiating of classes, where they are used,
- and many more.

And since the testability of code can be described by quantifiable criteria, it should be possible to quantify the testability itself.

Is there something like a "testability index"? How to quantify/measure the testability of an application?

Comment: The easiest way to see if a piece of code is unit-testable is by attempting to write some unit tests against it.  The harder that process is, the less unit-testable your code is.

Comment: Regardless whether such a measure is possible, it's relationship to "good" or "useful" won't be absolute.

Comment: If you make every member of a class public, this will significantly increase your component's "unit-testability index". However, it will probably not increase the quality of its design.

Comment: @DocBrown You're right, it's about the code quality in general, but is not a good criterion for the testablility.

Comment: Another interesting measure is how important it is to test the code independently (in a unit test). Large quantities of low value tests impede development. Many of the benefits of low-level unit testing can be achieved by dynamically checking invariants and postconditions in all running code, without destroying encapsulation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Have you read the question? Sorry, but your comment is something like "the sun rises in the east" -- absolutely correct and absolutely unsubstantial/needless.

Comment: @all, who downvoted the question: why? Please give me a feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @FrankHileman It's a good point. I'm currently discussing this subject in my actual project -- where/when should we write real unit tests (means low-leved, with mocked dependencies) and where would be enough to run integration/functional tests. But it goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Once the verb "mocking" enters, poor quality testing often ensues. Mocking has legitimate uses, for example in validation of public protocols, but most uses focus on internals that are rightfully encapsulated.

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but it probably has no good answer, other than the ones you provided. Robert Harvey's answer is actually the best one. Testability is similar to API usability. While you can acquire experience that helps in creating usable API's, the only way to determine API usability is to have people use it, examine the code written, and listen to opinions.

Comment: I might come back later with a better answer but I'd say the 'testability' of a piece of code is at least some-what dependent of its pureness (in terms of functional programming). If the piece of code you want to test does a `println` or `console.log` instead of return a string, it cannot be tested. If your code has side-effects, it's harder to test those side-effects. It's all about exposing an API where you can assert or expect a certain value.

Comment: @automatix: See JacquesB's answer below.  As my comment implied (but not actually stated), no, there is no such index, and frankly I don't see how the existence of one would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

No such index exist to my knowledge, and I don't think testability is quantifiable in a meaningful way.

The criteria you mention are indeed quantifiable, but they are not really related to testability.

Static methods or direct instantiation of objects does not prevent you from testing code. It just prevent you from mocking. But the need for mocking is itself a code smell which might indicate a problematic design.

If the code is overall well-designed, cyclomatic complexity just reflects the complexity of the business requirements. So it doesn't really tell you if the code is more or less testable, it just show you how much work you have to do if you want full branch coverage.